# Reading Emails from Google(GMAIL) API

Tags: php, google-api, gmail, gmail-imap

I have got the API to authenticate the user for GMAIL, the scope I used is **'https://mail.google.com/'**, authentication is done successfully, moving ahead I need to read mails through the access token, is there any class, please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google just now released API for managing user's gmail account. Please follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/)